# Returning Data from Chained Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to return data from a chained promise. In the below scenario how would I achieve that?

pseudocode:

```
mark = function(){
        return promiseA
    .then(function(data){ .....})
    .then(function(data){return new OBJECT});
}

steve = function() { mark().SomeProperty}
```

What is happening is mark() is undefined, if I return new Object form the first `.then` It all works. I want to be able to return data from the third or firth chained promise, how can i achieve that?

Comment: *"What is happening is mark() is undefined"* are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct your `function` syntax & then you need to use `.then` function which will get called when promise get resolved.

**Code**

```
function mark(){
        return promiseA
    .then(function(data){ .....})
    .then(function(data){return new OBJECT});
}

mark().then(function(data){
   steve = data.SomeProperty;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean

```
mark().then( res => steve = res.SomeProperty )
```

Answer (score -1):

The promise will not return any value but a promise... You've to set another value with the value you want. For example:

Pseudocode:

```
var mark = '';

promiseA
    .then(function(data) { return data })
    .then(function(data) { mark = new OBJECT });
}

steve = function() { mark.SomeProperty }
```

I've posted this answer before seeing @pankaj-parkar one, which may be a better solution depending the case.